# alloca vs fixed buffer for formatting strings

Tags: c

I need to log some messages in a function like:

```
void log(char* format, ...);
```

For the format buffer there are several methods:

Have a fixed size buffer. This will not cause overflow, but it may truncate the message.

```
void log1(char* format, ...)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Have a variable length buffer. This may cause overflow when allocating memory on the stack. I won't consider the case when the memory is allocated on heap. This is a design restriction.

```
void log2(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, args);
    char* buffer = (char*)alloca(length + 1);
    vsnprintf(buffer, length+1, format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

The function will be called from multiple threads, so keeping a common global buffer is not an option(too much locking). TLSs also is not an option because of some old compilers/executable formats limitation.

What version should I prefer? Is there any other obvious advantage/disadvantage of using first or second method?

Comment: The first solution is slightly faster because vsnprintf isn't called twice. If you assume that one line of log is never exessively long, then alloca is unlikely to trigger a stackoverflow. I'd go for the first solution and chose a reasonable size for BUFFER_SIZE (1000 to 2000 chars).

Comment: Suggest that an excessive long line is itself an error that should not propagate.  Hence I'd go with a generous fixed sized buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As worded, you should choose the variant which truncates the message because it is the only option you present which executes in a defined manner.

Answer (score 1):

> What version should I prefer? Is there any other obvious
>   advantage/disadvantage of using first or second method

The first method.

> The function will be called from multiple threads, so keeping a common
>   global buffer is not an option(too much locking).

IMHO, you are jumping to an unwarranted conclusion, or at least an unmeasured performance expectation. I consider this is a form of premature optimization.

I have used ram log's for many years in several embedded systems. (my choices: a fixed buffer length, and no truncation.  I used round-robin enqueue, with oldest message over-write.  The buffer size was typically 5 to 10 minutes of brief progress messages (with time stamps) during start up.) My ram log typically suspended capture after the selected time duration when working on start up issues (to avoid overwrite).  But otherwise the log ran continuously.

The ram log is very useful for investigating many other issues, including customer reported issues.  So, yes, in at least one project we shipped with the log enabled, and taught field service how to access it ... one customer learned some other equipment was inadvertently sending the unexpected loop-back code that our system was correctly responding to.)

On most practical systems,

- the sprintf() (or equivalent) into the ram buffer will complete in substantially less time than a typical context switch.
- if you do not have priority based preemptive scheduling (as vxWorks does), the enable of another task (because of interrupt or timer or networking input) will simply result in the current task continuing to run until a time slice, or it 'surrenders' the cpu.  Neither would cause a mutex collision.
- In vxWorks, in the embedded system, all the tasks using my log were the same priority (by a previous decision), so typically the log entry action would complete before the next 'enabled' same priority task would get to run, and thus none of the other tasks would even get a chance to enter the locked critical section.  But for design safety, the critical section locks (using semaphores) was in place.

Because of these factors I believe multiple threads or tasks will seldom 'collide' in the logging effort.

- Your results may vary ... this is something to measure (i.e. how many collisions occur per second in operation.)  But, I think not something to make a design decision about until you measure it.

---

FYI: On my 7 year old Dell, with ubuntu 12.04, I measure a 'typical' round-robin ram log enqueue at 5.4 us.  My typical enqueue is <80 chars, with 3 to 5 conversions (such as %d, %f, etc).  Also, I have observed that on my desktop, sprintf() is about twice as fast as stringstream i/o.  Another benchmark suggests that a semaphore enforced context switch takes about 14.6 us.

I have not yet explored the collision counts in my ram log, as I am not sure how to test.  Can one Linux thread or process preempt another? (if not, count should be 0) Future research for me.

---

Update:  (13:20)

FYI: On my Dell, I added a measurement for how long the critical section is locked (with only 1 thread, so no mutex hits (no lockout's? no collisions?). The time window is 1.5 us to 3.2 us, typically < 2 us.

All formatting (and time-stamping, and limit checks going into the log) are completed in the calling task's or thread's context prior to locking the RR buffer.  The lock is applied, the char's are transferred using simple loops into the RR buffer, and the lock is released.

This transfer takes somewhat less than half of the Log::enq() duration, and suggests a even smaller target time window within which a collision might occur.